# Are there any cold paddles that are BPA free?

Tags: food-safety, chemistry

There have been previous discussions on the cold paddles to use to rapidly cool soups, etc. One of the more common ones in the San Jamar line. However, on their website, it says that there is some possible exposure to chemicals like BPA when using this product. https://www.sanjamar.com/warning/  Is this a big concern? Are there any other equivalent products which are safer (BPA free)? Thanks.